# php value display

Tags: php

I wrote this code but its not displaying the images someone know how to fix it  ?

```
<?php $valuecredits = $account['credits'];
if ( $valuecredits > "10" ) {
echo "<img src='pbar/100.png' width='700' height='61' />";
}   
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Ok.  Have you looked at the resulting HTML in your browser?

Comment: You should probably show us the resulting HTML.

Comment: blanke nothing in the source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding `>=` insead of just `=`

```
if ( $valuecredits >= "10" ) {
 echo "<img src='pbar/100.png' width='700' height='61' />";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing `$valuecredits` with another string `"10"` .. what else did you expect to happen:

```
<?php 
    $valuecredits = (int)$account['credits'];
    if ( $valuecredits > 10 ) {
       echo '<img src="pbar/100.png" width="700" height="61" />';
    }   
?>
```

Comment: why the `(int)` code ? david way works `if ( $valuecredits >= "10" ) {
 echo "<img src='pbar/100.png' width='700' height='61' />";`

Answer (score 0):

Try using 10 instead of "10". You are using the comparison operator ">" which is I think for numeric variables only.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $valuecredits = $account['credits'];
if ( $valuecredits >= 10 ) {
echo "<img src='pbar/100.png' width='700' height='61' />";
}   
?>
```